# Regular results and Count(*) in the same query

Tags: sql, sqlite

Let's say I'm running the following sql SELECT query:

```
SELECT Name, Age FROM Friends;

Bilbo|111
Aragorn|69
```

I'd like to be able to get the total number of results **in the same query**.
However, if I do the following:

```
SELECT Count(*),Name, Age FROM Friends;

2|Aragorn|69
```

only the final result is displayed. Is there a way I get all results and still get the Count with a single SQLite query?

Comment: Your problem is that Bilbo was 41 when Aragorn was born, so Aragorn would only have been about 69 or 70, not 88.

Comment: 33 right? @AdrianWragg

Comment: @Naga You're thinking of Frodo.

Comment: @AdrianWragg I'll be honest, I trusted stack exchange on this one (http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/20217/how-old-is-aragorn-when-he-fights-at-helms-deep)

Comment: @BruceConnor In the book, it was around 17 years between Frodo getting the ring and his leaving the Shire. Jackson took a few (understandable) liberties with the timeline. :)

Comment: @AdrianWragg Oh crap! I read the books, but I never realised it had been so long. I just figured it was a few of years or so. =P

Comment: @BruceConnor \*sigh\* going to have to downvote you, sorry ... :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your DBMS supports Windowed Aggregate Functions it would be easy:

```
SELECT Count(*) OVER (),Name, Age FROM Friends;
```

Otherwise you have to (cross) join:

```
SELECT cnt,Name, Age FROM Friends, (SELECT Count(*) as cnt FROM Friends);
```

or use a Scalar Subquery:

```
SELECT (SELECT Count(*) FROM Friends) as cnt, Name, Age FROM Friends;
```

Comment: Could you comment how the 2nd and 3rd examples would change if I had a WHERE clause? The first example returned `near "(": syntax error`, so I'm guessing it's not supported. =/

Comment: You have to add the WHERE-condition to thecount query, too. That's why the OVER function is so nice to have

Comment: Silly question from an SQL newbie: In the 3rd option, is the Count performed only once or once per row?

Comment: A smart optimizer will do it only once :-)

Answer (score 1):

Normally, the results-set object that is returned can be queried for its length; so you don't put an aggregate function like `COUNT` into the SQL query itself, but rather just count how many rows are returned.

Comment: Unfortunately, I'm asking this question specifically to avoid doing that. This is for an android application, where and java takes ~ 1000 times longer than SQLite to count the rows. (In fact, I'm already using a separate SQLite count to significantly improve performance, this is question is meant to reduce my SQLite queries to 1 instead of 2 to improve performance a little more.)

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, use `UNION`:

```
SELECT Name, Age FROM Friends UNION SELECT 'Count', COUNT() FROM Friends;
```

Comment: (the comment I made earlier was mistaken, so I deleted it) This does work (if I add `(*)` after COUNT).